# How to use CommonsMailerPlugin in play 2.4

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I just migrated my app from play 2.2->play 2.3 and am now having trouble migrating it from play 2.3->play 2.4, especially with the CommonsMailerPlugin. I'm getting the following runtime error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ClassNotFoundException: play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin]
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:165) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at play.utils.Reflect$.getClass(Reflect.scala:142) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at play.api.Plugins$$anonfun$loadPlugins$1.apply(Plugins.scala:88) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at play.api.Plugins$$anonfun$loadPlugins$1.apply(Plugins.scala:87) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just follow instruction as per [Play 2.4 Mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537297/play-2-4-mailer) and remove a reference to the Mailer plugin from **conf/play.plugins** file.

In my case it was the only line in the file, so I deleted the file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Play 2.4 has new version of Mailer plugin.
And there was a package changes:

> com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin  - version 2.4.1
>   play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin - version 2.3.x

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have a 
libraryDependency "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1"  in my build.sbt and
     1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
in play.plugins but it still shows the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem when using securesocial plugin. Old version of securesocial was dependent of old version of play-mailer but I use new one when tried to migrate to Play 2.4. So I had to updated securesocial. May be this is your case when some other library in your project depends on old version of play-mailer and try to import it...

Comment: You are correct, I'm using play-authenticate, but switched over to the latest version which supports play 2.4. Still not sure why this is happening, do you know why this generally happens?

Comment: No. But did you look at full error stacktrace in log file?