# Play 2.4 Mailer

Tags: email, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework 2.4 and i am trying to send an email using play mailer plugin but  keep getting this error:

```
[ClassNotFoundException: play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin]
```

I asm using this dependenct:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1"
```

And this plugin:

```
1500:play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Where you have placed the plugin?

Comment: conf/play.plugins file

Comment: [play-mailer](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) for play 2.4 they didn't mention about plugin for configuring mailer, but for 2.3 they mentioning. Try without plugin.

Comment: tried it. same error!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130048/how-to-use-play-plugins-mailer-with-play-2-3-and-scala-2-11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I removed these lines in play.plugins file and clean the project (delete target and project folders) and it works for me.